# Lose reference to std::variant object after changing its type

Tags: c++, arrays, variant

Note that the problem can be reproduced by running the snippet below (I use wandbox with gcc 9.1)

So I have a `std::array` (size 2 for simplicity) of `std::variant` of two custom types (`Normal` and `Special`) `Normal` is specified as first type so upon class construction, the array is default-constructed with `Normal` objects. I change some internal data members of the first element of the array and print it out. Looks fine.

Now I want to set the second element of the array to `Special` object. I tried doing this both by assigning to a new value and using `emplace` according to this tutorial (https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/variant.html#changing-the-values)

However, when I try to change the internal data members of the second object (now typed `Special`) it seems like I'm not operating on the object in the original arrays. Print out results show default value of construction (0 in this case) I am new to using `std::variant` so I don't have a clue why it would be the case. How can I get the actual reference to the recently type-change variant object in my array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>
#include <variant>

struct Normal {
    struct Header {
        std::array<uint8_t, 2> reserved;
    };
    Normal() : frame{0}, payload{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(frame + sizeof(Header))} {}
    constexpr static auto LENGTH = 10;
    uint8_t frame[LENGTH];
    uint8_t* payload;
};

struct Special {
    struct Header {
        std::array<uint8_t, 3> reserved;
    };
    Special() : frame{0}, payload{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(frame + sizeof(Header))} {}
    constexpr static auto LENGTH = 11;
    uint8_t frame[LENGTH];
    uint8_t* payload;
};

std::array<std::variant<Normal, Special>, 2> handlers;
Normal* normal_handler;
Special* special_handler;

int main() {
    auto& nh = std::get<Normal>(handlers[0]);
    memset(nh.payload, 3, 3);
    normal_handler = &nh;

    handlers[1].emplace<1>(Special{});
    auto& sh = std::get<Special>(handlers[1]);
    memset(sh.payload, 4 ,4);
    // memset(std::get<Special>(handlers[1]).payload, 4, 4);
    special_handler = &sh;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Expect 3 bytes from 3rd bytes = 3
        std::cout << (int) normal_handler->frame[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        // Expect 4 bytes from 4th bytes = 4
        std::cout << (int) special_handler->frame[i] << " ";
        // std::cout << (int) std::get<Special>(handlers[1]).frame[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue isn't related to `std::variant`, the following code shows the same behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

struct Special {
    struct Header {
        std::array<uint8_t, 3> reserved;
    };
    Special() : frame{0}, payload{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(frame + sizeof(Header))} {}
    constexpr static auto LENGTH = 11;
    uint8_t frame[LENGTH];
    uint8_t* payload;
};

int main() {

    Special s1;
    s1 = Special{};
    memset(s1.payload, 4 ,4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        // Expect 4 bytes from 4th bytes = 4
        std::cout << (int) s1.frame[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

This line:

```
    s1 = Special{};
```

Creates a temporary `Special` object and then assigns it to `s1`. The default copy and move constructors will set `s1.payload` to the value of `payload` in the temporary. Therefore `s1.payload` is a dangling pointer to `frame` in the temporary object and the rest of your code therefore has undefined behaviour.

The simplest fix is to change the `payload` member into a function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

struct Special {
    struct Header {
        std::array<uint8_t, 3> reserved;
    };
    Special() : frame{0} {}
    constexpr static auto LENGTH = 11;
    uint8_t frame[LENGTH];
    uint8_t* payload() { return &frame[sizeof(Header)]; }
};

int main() {

    Special s1;
    s1 = Special{};
    memset(s1.payload(), 4 ,4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        // Expect 4 bytes from 4th bytes = 4
        std::cout << (int) s1.frame[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. I was caught up in the variant and failed to see the more fundamental issue.